# How to use JSON gem to parse select attributes in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, parsing

I am using httparty and json gem to go to a website and parse a body that contains something like:

```
{"id"=>12345, "slug"=>"mac-n-cheese", "name"=>"Bacon Dude", "email"=>"ilovebacon@cheese.com", "title"=>nil, "first_name"=>"Bacon", "last_name"=>"Dude", "facebook_id"=>nil,...}
```

The body contains a lot of information that I don't need. I only need to display name, email, and id. My current code:

```
def get_json
    url = "https://someurl.io/api/me"
    response = self.class.get(url, headers: { "authorization" => @auth_token })
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
```

What do I have to add on get_json method to fetch only id, name, and email when parsing JSON information from the website?

Answer (score 1):

If the body is in a JSON format, that means it's a string. You theoretically could parse the string to get the needed part of the body first, then parse it with `JSON.parse` to turn it to a Hash. But, I would **strongly recommend** not doing it, because you will end up doing much more expensive (and time consuming) exercise to avoid a simple `JSON.parse`.

The best approach is the one you are already using - parse the whole `request.body` and then access the data you need.

For what it's worth - if you are the owner (e.g. the developer) of the service that sends the data, you could skim down the data on that the sender side.

Also, if this is a Rails controller action, you don't need to use `request.body` - instead, you can rely on `params`, which will already be parsed by Rails and you get a hash to use, e.g.

```
name = params[:name]
email = params[:email]
id = params[:id]
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the input! It is not on controller, unfortunately. This is not a typical rails framework (this is inside a custom local gem, so it doesn't have MVC structure). However, do you mind explaining your second paragraph - to parse the whole `request.body` and access the data I need - how can I go to access specific data?

Comment: Well, you could parse the string. But, don't do that. What is wrong with parsing using `JSON.parse` and then accessing the data using the hash you get back?